# Importing ngbootstrap to angular 6 project breaks project

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, angular6

so, I have been trying to just add NgBootstrap to my angular 6 application--
steps:
-  I reference bootstrap dependency in Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>UserInterface</title>
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Then:

npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

I have worked down to the fact that the breaking change is in my App.Module.Ts, when I import the NgbModule,

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { ROUTES } from "./app.routes";
import { LayoutModule } from "./views/layout/layout.module";
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
        LayoutModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot()
]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Any obvious catches?

Comment: did you ever figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to remove the ***css and js*** file path from index.html.

I don't think it's necessary to add path in index.html.

I have created one sample example, you can see it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhzgqf?file=src%2Findex.html)

Also I will refer you this [reference](https://medium.com/@sunilk/getting-started-angular-6-and-ng-bootstrap-4-4b314e015c1c) site for more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer-- I will check them out!

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming to this question from Angular 9, look at your console when the page loads (ctrl-f5). Likely you need to `ng add @angular/localize`.